# Can I set/get variables in docker-compose.yml files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to have a variable in a `docker-compose.yml` for my project that represents a port and instead of putting `8080` everywhere in the file, I'd rather use it as a variable.

Is it possible to set variable, say in the beginning of the file, then reuse it in other places of the file?

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: Try, which way?

Comment: [https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an external .env file and include it in the docker-compose file.

```
$ cat .env
port=8080

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    port: "${port}"
```

**docker-compose.yml** and **.env** should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 3.4, you can re-use configuration parts using [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields#extension-fields). Valid *extension fields* have two requirements:

1. Should be located at the root of your Compose file.
2. Their name starts with the "x-" character sequence.

Here's an example:

```
version: '3.4'
x-logging:
  &default-logging
  options:
    max-size: '12m'
    max-file: '5'
  driver: json-file

services:
  web:
    image: myapp/web:latest
    logging: *default-logging
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    logging: *default-logging
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do these steps:

1. Make a file named `.env` beside your `docker-compose.yml` file
2. Set your variable there as `port=8080`
3. Use it inside your `docker-compose.yml` file as `$port` or `${port}`

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)